# Check if directory is symlink?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In `os` there's a function `os.path.islink(PATH)` which checks if `PATH` is symlink. But if fails when PATH is a symlink to some directory. Instead -- python thinks it is directory (`os.path.isdir(PATH)`). So how do I check if a dir is link?

**Edit**:

Here's what `bash` thinks:

```
~/scl/bkbkshit/Teaching: file 2_-_Classical_Mechanics_\(seminars\)
2_-_Classical_Mechanics_(seminars): symbolic link to `/home/boris/wrk/tchn/2_-_Classical_Mechanics_(seminars)'
```

and here's what `python` thinks:

```
In [8]: os.path.islink("2_-_Classical_Mechanics_(seminars)/")
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: Both `isdir` and `islink` return `True` for a symbolic link pointing to a directory on Python 2.7.3/OS X.  Could you post your code?

Comment: Is the problem the appending slash (`/`)?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: yep. It is.

Comment: Ok. interjay saw it like the same second as me ;)

Comment: for me, both python2 and python3 return `False` for `islink()`. The proposed solution did not work

Comment: Similar to @Soutzikevich, it also returns False for me. Symlink points to a directory. What can be happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because you put a slash at the end of the filename.

```
os.path.islink("2_-_Classical_Mechanics_(seminars)/")
                                                  ^
```

The trailing slash causes the OS to follow the link, so that the result is the target directory which is not a link. If you remove the slash, `islink` will return `True`.

The same thing happens in Bash as well:

```
g@ubuntu:~$ file aaa
aaa: symbolic link to `/etc'
g@ubuntu:~$ file aaa/
aaa/: directory
```