# Way to check if directory is a symlink via erlang

Tags: erlang

Is there a good way to check if a directory is a symlink in erlang? I found this for python: [Check if directory is symlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718006/check-if-directory-is-symlink) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170444/how-to-find-out-a-file-is-hard-link-or-symlink) for linux but I was wondering if there was an erlang specific way to do this in a pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`file:read_link_info`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_link_info-1)

```
-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").
is_symlink(Filename) ->
    {ok, Info} = file:read_link_info(FileName),
    Info#file_info.type == symlink.
```

Comment: This did not work for me when I tried locally on a folder with `touch a && ln -s a b`. It returns `false` for both `"a"` and `"b"` (`type` is `regular` for both). Does it work for you?

Comment: `file:read_link_info` works great for me here. Could you try it out once and update the answer? I'll delete my answer.